# Редиректы при переезде на новый домен

Tags: редирект

Сейчас в выдаче есть ссылка

'https://samara.domen.ru/bankrotstvo-fizicheskih-lic‎'

пытаюсь настроить редирект через '.htaccess'
  Прописал

'RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^samara.domen.ru$ [NC]'
'RewriteRule ^(.*) https://samara.new-domen.ru/ [NC,L,R=301]'

Меня редиректит на 'https://samara.new-domen.ru/‎'
  Получается, я теряю все, что написано после ".ru/"

Не могу понять, как сохранить и поддомен и остальной запрос, меняя только домен

Answer (score 0):

А ларчик-то просто открывался
Добавил $1 в конце и все заработало)